# Passing strings padded with white space into a byte[]

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer

I am using Google Play services for a real time multiplayer game in Unity 3d. When sending the data in a byte[] in the multiplayer update I have to pad certain entries going into the byte[] with white space so all entries are a certain length. I am having a problem where they don't have the white spaces anymore when I get the strings back from the byte[].

For example I have a string called username that is set to "test name " with 6 white spaces on the end in order to take up 15 bytes.

I add the string to the byte[] like so:

```
updateMessage.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username));
```

Then to get the part back out I use this code:

```
string username = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 38, 15);
```

38 is the index where the username string should start and it should be 15 bytes long. It actually ends up going into the next string I have stored because it doesn't have the white spaces anymore.

Is there a way to make sure the white spaces stay in the string so that I keep the padding after pulling it from the byte[]?

Comment: What are the contents of the byte array `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username)` returns?

Comment: You may be able to use ` ` (alt + 0160 on numpad); it's whitespace, but not ASCII 32. I don't know the underlying reason for the api trimming them. I have to use it in AutoCAD sometimes for a similar reason.

Comment: @immibis It returns the username string like it should and then part of the next string in the byte []. So say username is "test name" with 6 white spaces on the end to get to 15, and the next string is "second string" then it would return "test namesecond".

Comment: @Jon I will give that a shot and update as soon as I do. Thanks

Comment: @Jon I just tried that out and I get '?' for every one of those spaces I put in for padding in the strings.

Comment: @Jon Do you use a different encoding for those?

Comment: Never looked it up before, but it is apparently ASCII 255. The '?' may be normal if you are seeing it while inspecting variables in debug since it's non-printing. If you are seeing them while rendering, your font creation method probably only imports the most commonly used glyphs from the source font, by default; it is telling you "I don't know how to draw this".

Comment: @Jon Yeah I was thinking it was putting question marks as it didn't know the character. Any idea how I would get around this so it would still give me the blank spaces? Not sure if there is an encoding I can use to help out here.

Comment: You'll need to use 8-bit encoding to use characters beyond 127. Try UTF-8, which I incorrectly referred to as "ASCII".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immibis wants you to inspect the actual byte-array created by `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username)`

because your input:

```
{ t,e,s,t, ,n,a,m,e, , , , , , }
```

has probably become:

```
{ t,e,s,t, ,n,a,m,e,0,0,0,0,0,0} //null-terminated
{ t,e,s,t, ,n,a,m,e,0, , , , , } //also null-terminated
```

because of the underlying "friendliness" of C# strings.

---

You may be able to use the non-breaking space - " " (alt + 0160 on numpad), which is character 255, to pad your strings and circumvent the trimming behavior. However, byte values beyond 127 are not representable with ASCII encoding (7-bit) and fallback to "?" so you'll need to use UTF-8, which is a super-set of ASCII.

```
//C# strings and documents support full unicode (UTF-16)
//swap " " (space) for " " (non-breaking space) when uploading
updateMessage.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username.replace(" ", " ")));
//any characters that don't fit into ---------^ will be a "?"
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question but how do I count the amount of bytes per character in this situation since UTF-8 can have 1-4 bytes per character in a string? I feel that I will have a hard time being able to calculate this at runtime as different names will have different amounts of the white spaces. it will make it hard to determine how many bytes to use for each string when reading them.

Comment: @saboehnke, yeah, I didn't word that well; I'll fix it. Check this out: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm. The first chart shows how UTF-8 can substitute for ASCII. To go above 127, another byte (not bit) is added, and that allows you to request character values up to 2047, well beyond the required 255.

Comment: @saboehnke, now that I think about it, you could just pick any non-useful ASCII character under 127 and disallow it for usernames (~ tilde, for example). When you upload, just `string.replace()` ' ' for '~' and unswap after decoding. That would let your letters stay byte-sized, regardless of encoding used.

Comment: Ah yeah that could have worked. I ended up just getting rid of the set length and put a symbol at the end that would be an end symbol for me. Then I loop through the byte[] and add to an array of characters until I hit the end character. Then I combine the array into a string.